# Where to find list of available options for Clang-tidy "readability-identifier-naming" checker?

Tags: c++, clang, static-analysis, llvm-clang, clang-tidy

## Use case

I want to configure `readability-identifier-naming` checker for clang-tidy running on my codebase.

## Background

The checker in clang-tidy can be provided with CheckOptions, such like:

```
    clang-tidy -checks='-*,readability-identifier-naming' \ 
    -config="{CheckOptions: [ {key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassCase, value: CamelCase} ]}" main.cpp
```

An option can also be specified in a .clang-tidy file.

## Problem

Where do I find the list of available options (for a `readability-identifier-naming` check in this case) like e.g. the `ClassCase` from the line of code above?

The [official documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-identifier-naming.html) is not very specific, saying only "Many configuration options are available, in order to be able to create different rules for different kind of identifier."

## Results of Googling

I have found [this page](https://sarcasm.github.io/notes/dev/clang-tidy.html) on github, which explains it in a bit more detail (but still does not solve the problem).

I have also found a huge list in a file on a [Microsoft's repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/clang-tools-extra/blob/master/test/clang-tidy/readability-identifier-naming.cpp), but I have no idea where did they get that from.

## Further investigation

I thought, that maybe clang-tidy would dump all the possible options if asked for.
If you run

```
    clang-tidy -checks=* --dump-config
```

(or while specifying only `readability-identifier-naming` checker. It doesn't really matter, the output is the same)

```
    clang-tidy -checks='-*,readability-identifier-naming --dump-config
```

the dumped file includes only one option with respect to readability-identifier-naming, which is:

```
      - key:             readability-identifier-naming.IgnoreFailedSplit   
        value:           '0'
```

I was also trying to go through clang-tidy source code, but did not succeed.

## After all

I would be grateful if someone could point me to a place (if it exists) with the list of all the available CheckOptions.

Comment: You could always just check the source code. It's Open Source after all.

Comment: @JesperJuhl
"I was also trying to go through clang-tidy source code, but did not succeed."


Additionally, this does not feel right, since usage options should be presented in the documentation for users. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 1):

> Where do I find the list of available options (for a readability-identifier-naming check in this case) like e.g. the ClassCase from the line of code above?

The list has since appeared on the page you originally linked to which currently lives [here](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability/identifier-naming.html#options).

> I have found [this page](https://sarcasm.github.io/notes/dev/clang-tidy.html) on github, which explains it in a bit more detail (but still does not solve the problem).

Now it does!

Comment: New link:
https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability/identifier-naming.html#options

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to look into the source code of **tests** for this check [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/clang-tools-extra/blob/master/test/clang-tidy/readability-identifier-naming.cpp):

```
// RUN: %check_clang_tidy %s readability-identifier-naming %t -- \
// RUN:   -config='{CheckOptions: [ \
// RUN:     {key: readability-identifier-naming.AbstractClassCase, value: CamelCase}, \
// RUN:     {key: readability-identifier-naming.AbstractClassPrefix, value: 'A'}, \
...etc.
```

This list is not guaranteed to be exhaustive since it's only a command used for testing. To really be sure you'll have to look into the source code of the check itself [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/clang-tools-extra/blob/master/clang-tidy/readability/IdentifierNamingCheck.cpp) and you'll find all the naming keys:

```
#define NAMING_KEYS(m) \
    m(Namespace) \
    m(InlineNamespace) \
    m(EnumConstant) \
    ...
```

These naming keys are then stringized to `StylenaNames[]`. Then look into the `IdentifierNamingCheck::storeOptions()` function:

```
  for (size_t i = 0; i < SK_Count; ++i) {
    Options.store(Opts, (StyleNames[i] + "Case").str(),
                  toString(NamingStyles[i].Case));
    Options.store(Opts, (StyleNames[i] + "Prefix").str(),
                  NamingStyles[i].Prefix);
    Options.store(Opts, (StyleNames[i] + "Suffix").str(),
                  NamingStyles[i].Suffix);
  }
```

and you'll see that each naming key concatenated with Case, Prefix or Suffix can be specified as an option. That gives you the definitive list of possible options for this check.